# Relationship between the solution of $\arg\!\min_a |\frac{x}{|x|_1} - ay|_1$ and that of $\arg\!\min_b |\frac{y}{|y|_1} - bx|_1$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

Here $x, y$ are non-negative real vectors, $|x|_1 \neq 0, |y|_1 \neq 0$ and $a, b$ are real scalars. I am thinking that

$$
\arg\!\min_a |\frac{x}{|x|_1} - ay|_1 = \arg\!\min_a |x - a|x|_1y|_1$$

and similarly
\begin{align*}
\arg\!\min_b |\frac{y}{|y|_1} - bx|_1 = \arg\!\min_b |bx - \frac{y}{|y|_1}|_1 \\
\neq \arg\!\min_b |x - \frac{y}{b|y|_1}|_1
\end{align*}

If I solve for one of them, can I somehow algebraically get the solution of the other one?

Comment: $\arg\!\min_b |bx - u|_1
\ne\arg\!\min_b |x - \frac ub|_1.$

Comment: Ah, oops. With that error corrected, if I solve for LHS, can I get RHS without doing optimization again?